# Redefinition of Enumerator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sdwebimage, mwphotobrowser

I am using the SDWebImage component in my project.  Recently, I also decided to add MWPhotoBrowser (which uses SDWebImage).   After installing MWPhotoBrowser I can no longer compile without receiving numerous errors.   I am certain this is because the SDWebImage version is different across components I use.

As soon as I add the location of the header files for MWPhotoBrowser (which include SDWebImage) to my user search path I start getting these errors.

Any guidance / help as to how I can sandbox the libraries that MWPhotoBrowser needs so it doesn't affect the rest of my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than modifying any of the browser code I decided to eliminate my copies of SdWebimage and leverage those included in MWPhotobrowser instead.  Not ideal, but I think the proper solution is to modify MWPhotobrowser to use these libraries as sub modules.